# A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RxString' in flutter Getx

Tags: flutter, base64, state-management, flutter-getx, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert image to base64 text in Getx controller but it shows error saying "A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RxString'".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 10):

```
final RxString rxstring = 'Hello'.obs;

rxstring.value = 'Hi'; // <-- this can change the value of the Rx variable and also trigger its listeners
```

Comment: saved the day....